# Angular2 - Materialize - dynamic icons

Tags: angular, icons, materialize

In angular2 I'm using Materialize.css and I wanted the icon to be dependant of a value in my model.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" 
   [class.active]="(tab.id == active)" 
   (click)="go(tab.id)">
     <a href="#">
       <i class="material-icons left">{{complete(tab.id)}}</i>
       {{tab.name}}
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with

```
public tabs = [
  {id: "great", name: "I'm great"},
  {id: "personal", name: "Persoonlijk"},
  {id: "identity", name: "Identiteit"},
  {id: "prefs", name: "Voorkeuren"},
  {id: "available", name: "Beschikbaar"}];
```

The "active" class and the "go" method work fine, the (Dutch) labels appear correct, however in my method "complete" I get "undefined" as value for "tabid".

```
complete(tabid) {
  console.log(tabid);
  return (this.candidate && this.candidate.complete[tabid]) ? "done" : "crop_square"
}
```

Any pointer would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{{complete(tab.id)}}
```

try this:

```
{{(candidate && candidate.complete[tab.id]) ? "done" : "crop_square"}}
```